# Why Go Programs need runtime support

Tags: go, goinstall

It's said that Golang is the *compiled* language, but what does it mean by *compiled*? If golang application is compiled to machine code, why can't I just distribute the binary (of course on corresponding arch and platform) instead of `go install` stuff?

Comment: You don't need `go install` and stuff to run a compiled go binary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once you compile a binary you *can* distribute it onto machines with the same architecture.  `go install,` `go run,` etc. is just necessary for compilation.

Comment: Not just the same, but the target. I build on whatever machine I'm on and deploy on four or five different systems.

Comment: `go install/run` is not related to compiling.

Comment: @Erikw. `go install` *compiles* and installs, and is how you build a non-main package. `go run` *compiles* in a temp location, then executes the resulting binary.

Comment: @JimB Oh that's true. What I was thinking about is that `install` is not necessary for compilation; `go build` would suffice. Useless however since the compiled package would not be installed and thus deleted when $WORK is deleted after the completion of the command.

Comment: One of Go's unique features is that APIs are distributed *as source code*, not as `.jar`, `.dll`, `.so` or other binary packages. This is practicable because Go compiles so fast. At a stroke, it solves portability issues very simply, without resorting to needing a virtual machine (JVM etc). The (minor) downside is that producing closed-source APIs is tricky, to say the least.

Comment: @Rick-777, "distributing APIs" (for what it stands) without the source code [might be implemented some time later](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2775).