# Do I need the Go language runtime to run a compiled Go application?

Tags: windows, go

With the Go programming language when I build an executable on Windows do I need the Go runtime installed to run the application on another machine?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As long as any dependencies your program has are installed on the machine running the program, or your program is statically compiled, the user will be able to run your program without installing anything. A better answer might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23072968/3747083).